# How accurate is Cosmos DB's _ts timestamp? (time drift)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I would like to store events with timestamps, and I need clients to be able to retrieve them in the order in which they were stored. However, I'm wondering how much time drift may exist in the Cosmos DB storage layer: the machines that perform the writes may be off by a few seconds in their time synchronization, and so an event that really happened later is registered as having happened earlier than another event. I can tolerate up to 1s of time drift, but more than that and there may start being weird effects on the client side.

Comment: `_ts` is the time when Cosmos DB writes the document which may or may not be the date/time an event has occurred. You may want to save the event timestamp as a property in your document.

Comment: If you worried about cosmosdb time drift, how about sending the server time of your running program? That's made the time more accurate.

Comment: @QAQ because then I have to worry about server skew :P I was hoping Cosmos would have solved the skew issue for me

Answer (score 2):

The _ts property on Cosmos is accurate and there is no clock skew either between replicas during leader election or during regional failover.