# Cosmos DB: How to store _ts in another document property at the time of creation?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, timestamp, azure-cosmosdb

When I insert a new document, I'd like Cosmos to automatically assign `_ts` to another document property. I think this may be possible with a stored procedure, but going through one [increases RU costs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units).

> Script usage: As with queries, stored procedures and triggers consume
> RUs based on the complexity of the operations that are performed. As
> you develop your application, inspect the request charge header to
> better understand how much RU capacity each operation consumes.

Is there another way to copy over `_ts`? The reason I want to do this is so I can track the original insertion time. `_ts` gets updated with each document change. I wish there was a way to configure a container so that Azure tracked the original insertion time in a separate system property.

Comment: Can you not create another property in the document and store the creation time in that property yourself?

Comment: I'd like the value defined by Azure because there is no clock skew in `_ts`. I need to sort items by date and would like the result to be accurate. I'm hosting APIs on Azure Functions and have experienced weird clock skew issues. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67165385/246392

Comment: FYI this question is closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67159455/how-accurate-is-cosmos-dbs-ts-timestamp-time-drift). As for dealing with your own processing and clock drift: you might want to consider using a post-trigger procedure to modify your newly-created document and preserve `_ts` in another property. Yes, it'll cost a bit more, RU-wise, but there's not much you can do about that.